# Accessing a Lazy-Loaded field... Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, object-reference

I am sure I am just missing something basic so hope I can get my question across clearly.

I have a class named ItemData which implements an interface IITemData. Within the class ItemData I have the following:

[image]

However when I am trying to use this ItemData class (via the interface) it looks like this ComponentType is loading okay:

[image]

But when I am trying to access it in a lambda expression:

[image]
 I keep getting the Object Reference error from the above.

[image]

I have the feeling I am just missing something straight forward.

Comment: Did you check all 22 elements of the original list? Do they all have the `Name` in place?

Comment: It seems you should dereference originalList with indexes since it is a list of collections of ItemData, right? So you may try with **originalList[index]**.Where().

Comment: I think you are onto something... Looks like someone has been fudging about with my ComponentTypes in the database! Thanks for that! :)

Comment: Could you please add the code as text rather than images?

Comment: Are you sure the NullReferenceException occurs in the lamba expression? Change you debugger exception settings to break whenever a NullReferenceException occurs and you will see.

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because there is nothing special or unique to distinguish it from any other null reference exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with null check maybe, seems like some of the data in list are null

```
var sortedList = new List<IItemData>(new ItemData[]{originalList.Where(x => x?.ComponentType?.Name == "template").SingleOrDefault()});
```

Comment: Turns out someone had changed some IDs in the database this is sourced from and there were nulls in a couple of the rows! Should have checked in the first place but all sorted now. Thanks!